# Función de agregación dentro de otra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta query estoy intentado usar una función de agregación dentro de otra porque quiero sumar los resultados, y que no me aparezcan resultados iguales, ya use **distinct** pero no me funciona.

Este es el error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CodigoDeAlquiler, 
  CASE datepart(weekday, FechaDelAlquiler)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo' WHEN 2 THEN 'Lunes'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Martes'  WHEN 4 THEN 'Miercoles'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Jueves'  WHEN 6 THEN 'Viernes'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Sabado'
  END AS Dia, 
  FechaRealDevolucion, 
  l.Titulo,
  cl.NumeroDeCopia, 
  c.NombresDelCliente + ' ' + c.ApellidosDelCliente AS Cliente,
  SUM(COUNT(alq.CodigoDeAlquiler)) AS Total
FROM AlquileresDelLibro alq
  INNER JOIN Clientes c
    ON alq.ClienteId = c.Id
  INNER JOIN CopiasDelLibro cl
    ON alq.CopiaDelLibroId = cl.Id
  INNER JOIN Libros l
    ON cl.LibroId = l.Id
WHERE datepart(week, FechaDelAlquiler) = datepart(week, getdate())
GROUP BY
  CodigoDeAlquiler, datepart(weekday, FechaDelAlquiler),
  FechaRealDevolucion, l.Titulo, cl.NumeroDeCopia,
  c.NombresDelCliente, c.ApellidosDelCliente
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY Dia ASC
```

Comment: intenta correr el query sin esto `sum(count(alq.CodigoDeAlquiler)) as Total`

Comment: `sum(count(alq.CodigoDeAlquiler))` es inválido, no puedes anidar funciones de agregación de esta forma, ¿Qué es lo que buscas?

Comment: @Freison, bienvenido a StackOverflow. En preguntas de este tipo, creo que lo ideal es poner una pequeña muestra de los datos que hay en la(s) tablas subyacentes y el resultado que estos datos debieran producir. De esta manera es más fácil entender lo que quieres conseguir, pues de leer la consulta es más dificil extraer la idea. Lo que has escrito en código, obviamente, no se puede hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una sub-consulta entonces

```
SELECT
  CodigoDeAlquiler, Dia, FechaRealDevolucion,
  Titulo, NumeroDeCopia, Cliente,
  SUM(Total) AS Total
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CodigoDeAlquiler, 
    CASE DATEPART(weekday, FechaDelAlquiler)
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Domingo' WHEN 2 THEN 'Lunes'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'Martes'  WHEN 4 THEN 'Miercoles'
      WHEN 5 THEN 'Jueves'  WHEN 6 THEN 'Viernes'
      WHEN 7 THEN 'Sabado'
    END AS Dia, 
    FechaRealDevolucion, 
    l.Titulo,
    cl.NumeroDeCopia, 
    c.NombresDelCliente + ' ' + c.ApellidosDelCliente AS Cliente,
    COUNT(alq.CodigoDeAlquiler) AS Total
  FROM AlquileresDelLibro alq
    INNER JOIN Clientes c
      ON alq.ClienteId = c.Id
    INNER JOIN CopiasDelLibro cl
      ON alq.CopiaDelLibroId = cl.Id
    INNER JOIN Libros l
      ON cl.LibroId = l.Id
  WHERE DATEPART(week, FechaDelAlquiler) = DATEPART(week, getdate())
  GROUP BY
    CodigoDeAlquiler, DATEPART(weekday,FechaDelAlquiler),
    FechaRealDevolucion, l.Titulo, cl.NumeroDeCopia,
    c.NombresDelCliente, c.ApellidosDelCliente
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
  ORDER BY Dia ASC
) AS x
GROUP BY 
  CodigoDeAlquiler, Dia, FechaRealDevolucion, Titulo, NumeroDeCopia, Cliente
```